# Создание окна, информирующего о долгой загрузке GUI

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, qt-designer, qthread

Есть приложение:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class StartingWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(StartingWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btn1.clicked.connect(self.add_row)

    def add_row(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setText('Ожидайте заавершения операции')
        self.label.show()
        for i in range(1000000):
            self.ui.table.insertRow(i)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.ui.table.setItem(i,0, item)
            self.ui.table.item(i,0).setText("example1")


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.table.setRowCount(0)
        self.table.setColumnCount(1)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.table)

        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn1.setText('btn1')
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


app1 = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
start_win = StartingWindow()

start_win.show()
sys.exit(app1.exec_())
```

При нажатии на кнопку выполняется долгая функция `add_row()`, изменяющая графический интерфейс. Необходимо выводить дополнительное окно, которое сообщало бы, что программа не зависла, а обрабатывает сигнал.

Реализация с `QMessageBox` не подходит, т.к. прерывает выполнение и ожидает нажатия кнопки. Была идея вызывать `QMessageBox` и закрывать его программно, но не нашел как это сделать.

`QDialog` тоже не подходит, т.к. при вызове его через `.show()` текст внутри него отображается после завершения функции.

Использовать **`два`** потока не получилось, так как функция изменяет интерфейс и прописывать испускание сигналов - слишком обширная работа.

Есть идеи как реализовать эту задумку? 
Может быть использовать несколько процессов? (до этого их не использовал и пока не знаю их тонкостей)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Долгая функция должна выполняться в дополнительном потоке, из которого вы передаете какие-то данные в основной поток и там их визуализируете.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.table.setRowCount(0)
        self.table.setColumnCount(1)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn1.setText('Start thread')
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, numStart, numEnd):
        super().__init__()
        self.numStart = numStart
        self.numEnd = numEnd

    def run(self):
        for i in range(self.numStart, self.numEnd):
            self.msleep(100)                                # имитируем длительную загрузку 
            self.threadSignal.emit(i)
        self.finished.emit()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        

class StartingWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StartingWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btn1.clicked.connect(self.add_row)
        
        self.thread = None                                              
        self.numStart = 0
        self.numEnd = 1_000_000

    def add_row(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.label.setWindowFlags(
            self.windowFlags() | 
            QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | 
            QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        )        
        self.label.setText('Ожидайте заавершения операции')
        self.movie = QtGui.QMovie('loading.gif')
        self.label.setMovie(self.movie)        
        self.movie.start()
        self.label.show()
        
        if self.thread is None:
            self.thread = WorkThread(self.numStart, self.numEnd)
            self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.on_threadSignal)
            self.thread.finished.connect(self.threadFinished)
            self.thread.start()
            self.ui.btn1.setText("Stop thread")
        else:
            self.label.close()
            self.thread.terminate()
            self.thread = None
            self.ui.btn1.setText("Start thread")
            self.numStart += 1
            
    def on_threadSignal(self, num):
        rows = self.ui.table.rowCount()
        self.ui.table.insertRow(rows)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(f"example1 {num}")
        self.ui.table.setItem(rows, 0, item)
        self.numStart = num

    def threadFinished(self):
        self.movie.stop()
        self.label.close()
        self.thread = None
        self.ui.btn1.setText("Start thread")
        if self.numStart+1 == self.numEnd:
            self.numStart = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app1 = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    start_win = StartingWindow()
    start_win.show()
    sys.exit(app1.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]